# AWS elastic beanstalk environment health is severe

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Local branch is linked to Develop branch and is working absolutely fine. But on AWS ebs it is showing the logs
"no repository for outhApplication repository was found, looks like this entity is not registered in your default connection".

I have tried multiple solution related to entity path. e.g => changing env configuration of entity path in ebs, used "autoloadentities : true". it is still not working for me.

Node version is 12.

Should i change load balancer with new target group and security id?
It seems to be only platform issue.